# Limiting single button clicks in an environment using JavaScript objects and React

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects, mouseclick-event

In this program, the button is active like under the picture when the user clicked the button.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wbg4.png)

These all are made with javascript Objects. If clicked Button, object value change button's value.
If the advanced user clicks more than one button in the program, the previous button should be disabled.

These codes are composed of the atomic design pattern, and the related codes are as follows.
First Code about that page.

```
const SeeAll = () => {
const [on, setOn] = useState({
    sum: false,
    payWith: false,
    sale: false,
    cashInput: false,
    cashSum: false,
    credit: false,
    creditCom: false
});

const setDetail = (key, e) => {
    let value = on[key];

    setOn({
        ...on,
        [key]: !value
    })
}

return (
    /*생략*/
                    <Receipt
                        map="false"
                        event={setDetail}
                        on={on}/>
    /*생략*/
)
}
```

The second Code contains these buttons.

```
const SellerReceipt = ({
    posNum,
    posName,
    order,
    call,
    map,
    event,
    on
}) => {
return (
    /*생략*/

        <Btn placeholder="매출 합계" event={() => event('sum')} onKey={on["sum"]} />
        <Btn placeholder="결제 수단 별 매출내역" event={() => event('payWith')}  onKey={on["payWith"]}/>
        <Btn placeholder="할인 매출내역" event={() => event('sale')}  onKey={on["sale"]}/>
        <Btn placeholder="현금시재 입력내역" event={() => event('cashInput')}  onKey={on["cashInput"]}/>
        <Btn placeholder="현금 정산액" event={() => event('cashSum')}  onKey={on["cashSum"]}/>
        <Btn placeholder="신용카드정산 내역" event={() => event('credit')}  onKey={on["credit"]}/>
        <Btn placeholder="카드사별 매출내역" event={() => event('creditCom')}  onKey={on["creditCom"]}/>
    </div>

)
}
```

Third code about Button.

```
const SellerBtn = ({placeholder, event, onKey}) => {
return (
    <button
        onClick={event}
        className="sellerBtn"
        style={{
            backgroundColor: `${onKey
                ? 'rgb(100,100,100)'
                : 'rgb(238,238,238)'}`,
            color: `${onKey
                ? 'white'
                : 'black'}`
        }}>{placeholder}</button>
)
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you always want your buttons to be mutually exclusive. If that's the case, the simplest solution should be:

```
const SeeAll = () => {
  const [on, setOn] = useState(null); // or empty string, since you want nothing selected in the beginning
  const setDetail = (key, e) => {
  // button already clicked? set it to null
    setOn(on === key ? null : key)
  }
  return (...)
}

const SellerReceipt = ({ posNum, posName, order, call, map, event, on }) => { 
  return ( 
        <Btn placeholder="매출 합계" event={() => event('sum')} onKey={on === "sum"} />
        <Btn placeholder="결제 수단 별 매출내역" event={() => event('payWith')}  onKey={on === "payWith"}/>
        // more buttons
    </div>
  )
}
```